# Proper way to handle an exception and clean up when function has only an iterator

Tags: c++, exception, iterator

As per the title, I'm curious how to clean up partial work in the case of an exception thrown.  In this case, after adding to an out iterator.

Imagine a function like std::copy_if() [callback ommitted for simplicity]

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename T>
void doSomethingIf(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator outputIterator)
{
   // For simplicity sake I'll divide the calculation and pushing back
   // results to the output iterator
   int count = std::distance(begin, end);
   std::vector<T> tmp{};
   int i = 0;
   while (i < count) {
       T t = someCalculation(*(begin+i));
       tmp.push_back(t);
   }

   // All fine and dandy, but we need to get everything on the output Iterator
   try {
       for (auto t: tmp) {
           *outputIterator++ = t;
       }
   } catch (const std::exception& e) {
       // How to "undo" our partial work
   }
}
```

Worth noting, I am calling it like

```
std::vector<int> output{};
std::vector<int> input{}; 
// Fill up input
doSomethingIf(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output));
```

Comment: make a copy of the contents of the outputiterator and then restore in the catch

Comment: This depends on a lot.  Can you "rewind" the output iterator?  Can you read from it first to save the original value (to be able to restore it when the exception is thrown)?  What throws the exception?  If it is something related to `outputIterator`, it may be left in a state that you cannot make any modifications or writes to.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Probably depends a lot on what's being worked on. :|

Comment: I'd say `doSomethingIf()` doesn't have enough information to do this rollback.

Comment: That's the way I'm starting to lean.... thank you for the input.

Comment: You could perhaps throw a custom exception containing the initial value for `outputIterator` (or a valid version thereof if iterators could be invalidated by adding to the `OutputIterator`). The caller would then at least have a chance of cleaning up. Perhaps you could then create a set of wrapper overloads for the common containers you aim to support that calls `doSomethingIf` and cleans up upon exception?

Comment: Something to think about for sure.  No silver bullet here, and that sounds better than nothing.